# How many types of webbing does Spider-Man have?

Tags: marvel, spider-man, powers

I know this may not be an easy question to answer, but it occured to me... Over the years, Peter Parker has made a number of different types of webbing. Considering that the webbing is, more or less, artificial, Peter has tweaked it to have various effects for specific utilitarian reasons. going as far back as the **1967 Spider-Man** cartoon, we have examples of Peter upgrading his webbing in various ways. Off of memory, I know he made some that was:

- Electricity proof
- Anti-magnetic
- Super stretchy without breaking
- Extra strong
- "Tempered" webbing that was "stronger than steel".

In the **1982 Spider-Man** cartoon where he was up against a radioactive Sandman [thanks to some Martian soil], Spidey protected himself from electrocution via covering himself in a webbing that was "rubber based".

In **Spider-Man: The Animated Series** in order to defeat Hydroman, he created a "coagulating" web fluid.

And in various video games, he has had some form of "combustible" web fluid as well.

In the comics he's also had impact webbing which shoots out in projectiles.

So I was wondering... all totaled, how many different types of webbing does Spider-Man have, and what are their effects? Are there any variations which Peter carries regularly which we should know about?

If we have scans that can showcase them or examples from his various shows where they were used, we can create a list here, and then continue adding to it.

Comment: Lots. And lots and lots. https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Web-Shooters and even more when the script called for it.

Comment: Also, how many webs could a Spider-Man web if a Spider-Man could web webs?

Answer (score 19):

Your question doesn't state a specific canon or universe so specifically in the Marvel Cinematic Universe (Earth-199999) Spider-Man originally only has one type of webs, his normal ones. He creates the mixture himself and does improve on it but it is generally just the same webbing. He is up to at least version 3.01 as we see his doodles in class when he is making it.

[image: _Spider-Man: Homecoming_ - Peter's doodles in class showing his latest test batch of webbing]
<sub>*Spider-Man: Homecoming* - Peter's doodles in class showing his latest test batch of webbing.</sub>

However, Tony Stark (Iron Man) gives Peter an upgraded suit in which there are 576 types of webbing.

> **Suit Lady:** Would you like to see more options? You have 576 possible web-shooter combinations.
>
> <sub>*Spider-Man: Homecoming*</sub>

During the events of the film we see the Normal Web, Sticking Web, Ricochet Web, Splitter Web, Web Grenades, Taser Web, Spider Tracers and if it counts the web shooters also have a Spider-Signal. These are just the ones we see being used and/or named, in the film we also see the selection screen in which we can make out:

[image: _Spider-Man: Homecoming_ - Peter's web selection screen]
<sub>*Spider-Man: Homecoming* - Peter's web selection screen.</sub>

- Taser Web
- Venom Web
- Timer Web
- Stun Web
- Arrow Web
- Shield Web
- Hook Web
- Grab Web
- Spear Web
- Sticky Web
- Net Web

The suit also has capabilities of instant kill which might be a different type of webbing or it could just "shoot harder", I don't think we know. And it also has the option for rapid fire but this could just be the normal web shooters just firing quickly rather than a specific type of webbing.

> **Suit Lady:** Would you like me to engage Enhanced Combat Mode?
>
> **Peter:** Uh, Enhanced Combat Mode? Yeah.
>
> **Suit Lady:** Activating Instant Kill.
>
> [...]
>
> **Suit Lady:** Rapid-fire is the default for Enhanced Combat Mode.
>
> <sub>*Spider-Man: Homecoming*</sub>

Comment: The question is: How many of those options actually involve specialized types of webbing vs. specialized application of regular webbing. E.g. stuff like 'net web' sounds more like regular web launched in a particular way to form a net as opposed to being a specialized web fluid.

Comment: @Suthek I presume net webbing might actually not be sticky so that'd be a specialised type probably. As far as I know we haven't seen too many of them so it is somewhat unclear.

Comment: 576 is a very composite number, so it is probably the result of several settings multiplied together.  e.g. It could be 12 different web types times 6 different fire rates times 8 different muzzle velocities, or some-such.  It certainly doesn't mean there are 576 different types of webbing.  The suit even explicitly says "combinations".

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Sure I tried not to expand on that too much in case I confused matters, wanted to leave it with mainly just the quote so people could see what it meant.

Answer (score 1):

Magnesium webbing is the fire web from the PlayStation game. It was used to kill symbiotes, and not available on levels with human enemies. He could also shoot impact webbing in that game and the magnesium impact webbing would shoot a fireball.